# Vite Rollup config for css and font assets

Tags: config, vite, cdn, rollup

I'm using Vite for deploying scss and js assets to my CDN and use them on my website. It can be seen as a library-like mode usage of Vite.

All in all it is working but all files (css, js, font-files) are beeing built directly into the dist folder. I would like to store the font-files in a /dist/font folder.

How can I accompish that?
I already tried to prefix assetFileNames with "font/" but that results in all files beeing built into /dist/font.

Here is my vite.config.js

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject'

export default {
    base: './',
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                app: resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/app.js'),
                a: resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/theme-a.scss'),
                b: resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/theme-b.scss'),
                c: resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss/theme-c.scss')
            },
            output: {
                assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]',
                chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
                entryFileNames: '[name].js'
            },
            plugins: [
                inject({
                    modules: {
                        $: 'jquery',
                        jQuery: 'jquery'
                    }
                }),
                terser({
                    format: {
                        comments: false
                    }
                })
            ]
        }
    }
}
```